# Tema do site com problemas

Tags: bug, status-pronto, layout

Fazia tempo que eu não entrava no SOpt, quando entrei fiquei surpreso - não conseguia ler nada...

Aí fui ver o problema e era o tema escuro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pra mim, fica desse jeito assim - fundo branco, fonte em cinza claro. SO em inglês não tem esse problema.

#### Atualização:

O tema claro também tem problema, se usar um browser cuja cor default não seja branco fica aparente:

[image: fundo do browser "vazando" no site]

Comment: O claro também está com problema: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxXaj.png - Acabo de constatar que está sem cor de fundo, quando o default do browser não é branco fica evidente (e um pouco mais cedo estava ok, foi recente isso).  - verifiquei no SOzão e lá ainda está normal.

Comment: Talvez esteja relacionado com a [recente mudança nas cores do site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393939/401803). Ou seja, mais uma alteração de layout que ninguém pediu, e que pelo jeito não foi devidamente testada (infelizmente essa situação tem sido uma constante no site)

Comment: Complementando, isso foi [reportado no Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393958/401803). Quem quiser, pode acompanhar por lá pra ver se eles confirmam que a causa foi essa mesmo

Comment: @Leonardo, parece que foi corrigido. Testei aqui e agora está normal (feio, mas pelo menos legível)

Comment: é, agora parece que está ok...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obrigado por nos avisar. A correção foi enviada em 20/10/2023.

Quando a atualização foi feita, havia uma lógica estranha em todos os sites internacionais que fazia com que as novas cores não fossem aplicadas de forma consistente.